# Listview is resizing correctly in Universal App Windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've got a XAML page which is broken down with a grid as follows:

```
<Grid Background="Green">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 </Grid>
```

The first and third row contain a `TextBlock` each and are set to auto-resize to their height and the ListView is contained in the middle row and it is suppose to stretch within the area.

The ListView appears to be resized based on the number of items rather than the available visible area that should be allocated to the middle row.

This has 2 side effects:

1. I can't scroll to view the other items
2. It pushes the `TextBlock` in the third row out of the screen.

If I set a specific height on the ListView, it works as expected but I want my ListView to use the entire area of the screen between the top and bottom rows.

It displays as expected in the IDE, but no data is loaded but I can clearly see my top and bottom row (in green) and I can see the ListView is stretched between these 2 rows.

I've used this numerous times in the past but with a universal app for Windows 10, so I'm wondering if this is a new behaviour I'm not aware of or is this a bug?

This is full code without the DataTemplate for clarity sake. Just to be clear, my DataTemplate is displaying correctly, but I just can't scroll as there is no scrollbar since the listview is stretched based on the items, rather than being restricted to the available area of the middle row.

```
<Grid Background="Green">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Top Row" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Background="Red">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                     ....
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Text="bottom row" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As I've tried with simple *TextBlock* as *DataTemplate*, I haven't encountered problems on device and emulator. Can you share a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your ListView in a ScrollView.  This will fill the empty area and add a scroll bar as the list overflows the empty area.

Comment: Hi, I was hopeful when I saw your comment thought I didn't think it was necessary as a ListView is supposed to handle this, but I thought it was worth the shot, but it didn't work. I've just found an article which I think states it's a bug and the only way around it is to set the height which is not a solution as I want this to work on multiple devices: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25bf0269-3a9a-46c4-989b-ad829de29167/uwplistview-with-horizontal-stack-panel-not-scrolling-windows-10-universal-app?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Please not: A ListView contains a ScrollViewer internally by its Control Template. Putting it into another scroll view or a stack panel will disable its data virtualization capabilities. As @Romasz stated above, that code should work, it must be something else in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It isn't a change in behaviour or a bug!

As someone mentioned that they tried to reproduce the problem and couldn't, I decided to do the same.

1. When I put my grid and ListView directly on the MainPage, I couldn't reproduce it.
2. When I put my grid and ListView on a sub-page (i.e. GridPage) and loaded it into the frame contained on the MainPage, I couldn't reproduce it

and that's when the penny dropped!!

In my code, I used (for the first time) a SplitView and this SplitView was contained in a grid with 2 rows and stupidly, both rows were set to "Auto" when I should have set the first one to Auto for my hamburger menu, logo and title and the second one should have been set to '*'.

The second I changed my second row to '*', the problem got sorted. It had nothing to do with the Grid Page which contained the grid I originally posted problem with.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Here is the full code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="White" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Margin="0,10,0,10">
            <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource SymbolButton}" 
     Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"
     FontSize="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"
     Command="{Binding HamburgerCommand}" >
                <FontIcon x:Name="Hamburger" 
                 FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
         Glyph="&#xE700;" 
         Foreground="#ff6600" />
            </ToggleButton>
        </Border>
        <Border Background="White" Grid.Row="0" 
         Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding SelectedSection, 
             Converter={StaticResource SectionImageConverter}}" 
             Height="20" Width="20" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="White" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Header" Text="{Binding SelectedSection,
             Converter={StaticResource 
             SectionTitleConverter}}" 
             Style="{StaticResource TagLineTextStyle}" 
             Foreground="#ff6600" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <SplitView x:Name="Splitter"
        IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPageOpen}"  
        DisplayMode="Inline" 
        Grid.Row="1">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox x:Name="SectionControl" SelectionMode="Single"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Background="White" 
                BorderThickness="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                SelectedItem="{Binding 
                                    SelectedSection, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource
                             SectionImageConverter}}" 
                             Height="17" Width="17"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding 
                             Converter={StaticResource
                             SectionTitleConverter}}"
                                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                Foreground="#ff6600" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding
                         ItemClickCommand}" 
                         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedSection}" />
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="SectionFrame"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Thanks again for the feedback/help. Much appreciated!